# Simple Wordpress function / plugin to redirect a site

Tags: plugins, functions, redirect

Is there a way to create a simple function that redirects every page of a site to another site?

I've Googled around but all the plugins / functions that I've found are only really meant for redirecting individual pages and not entire sites.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please rephrase your question in an [edit] and explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to do, what you already tried and where you are stuck. So far the question is too broad. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the plugin might solve your problem you could try something direct with WordPress API:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_142191_all_redirect' );
function wpse_142191_all_redirect() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://other-site.com', 301); 
            exit; //always die or exit after redirect
    }
}
```

Be careful with it,this will redirect the whole site on the home page of other site. I added a condition, maybe you do not want to be redirect as a user of website.

Comment: Why do you use template_redirect hook?

Comment: because `template_redirect` is for redirect

Comment: Yes, I know. But it's fired pretty late in the process, so it's not very optimal solution... I'm pretty sure you can run same action in `init` hook (since you don't rely on query at all).

Answer (score 2):

You might be just best off doing a redirect with the htaccess file.

> Redirect 301 / http://www.mynewwebsite.com

Further reading here: http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

[Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin gives you simple GUI to define URL-based redirects (301 or 302) to your site. It supports regular expressions, so I think it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Please add a short description to how the plugin works. Thanks

Comment: @Peter Goosen: I did. This plugin provides redirects based on regular expressions. There is nothing more to add here.

Comment: neither me. I kinda find this answer a good answer but I understood this is not allowed here

Comment: I know that you should not answer just with a link and so on. But I really don't know what else you can add in this case (this plugin does exactly what OP was asking, I guess). @PieterGoosen: Downvote is not a problem :) Although I'm really curious what is wrong with this answer in downvoter opinion...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`wp_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) but .htaccess is better in your case.

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```